# What does the "success" in the google cloud messaging push response mean?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android application where, among other things, I want to know how many installs are successfully answering to my push.

For example: 
According to my database, 1000 people installed my app. After that, I send a push notification to all of them and google returns something like this:

```
{"multicast_id":fakeidblabla,"success":581,"failure":419,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:fakeidblabla"},{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:fakeidblabla"},....]
```

What I want to really know is.. what does that `"success":581` mean?

Does it mean that those 581 are fully functional apps that are still running and that haven't been uninstalled?

Because I have a system that returns an OK everytime an install receives a push notification, so I should receive exactly 581 OK's but I don't. I receive less OK's.

Is my control system not working properly or maybe that `"success":581` doesn't mean that those installs are fully functional and still running?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream):

> **success**: Number of messages that were processed without an error.

So, the `success` parameter means the number of messages successfully proccessed by GCM, not received by the devices.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But how do you explain the big difference between those 581 successfully proccessed messages and the real amount of messages that my apps receive?
I understand a small difference but the difference can be about 200 messages lost..